# Powershell - Write-Output producing empty lines before and after output

Tags: powershell, csv, output

I'm creating a random output from a CSV using Powershell and, while I have got it to work properly, the output is really annoying because of the excess spaces between each output.

```
$L = ipcsv ln.csv | Get-Random | Select-Object Letter | Format-Table -HideTableHeaders
$N = ipcsv ln.csv | Get-Random | Select-Object Number | Format-Table -HideTableHeaders

Write-Output $L
Write-Output $N
```

I just have a basic CSV up to test with. Letter and Number columns, going from A-J and 1-10, is in the CSV. It outputs a random letter and number as intended, but the output comes out like this:

```
F                                                                                                                                                                                     



9
```

All of those empty lines flood the console if I do any more than 5 outputs, which gets pretty annoying. Given that the outputs are not separated in the actual script, I want the output to look something like this:

```
F
9
```

Is there any way to achieve this output?

Comment: The formatting cmdlets add the space (this is by design - they are formatting output - hence the name!). If you want `Select-Object` to return a single object property (instead of a new object), use its `-ExpandProperty` parameter.

Comment: Thank you, this does exactly as I wanted.

Comment: @Matt The duplicate given is questionable.

Comment: The OP is misusing format table. I have seen it enough that I tried to make a catch most for it. The answer to that question covers what the OP wants in this one exactly.